# How to convert raw material into finished product such that the availability in days for all product will be maximum

Tags: logic

How can I distribute 5000 Jars into finished product. Such that the all three product will become 0 after particular days.

I had a problem where I want to convert my available raw materials into finished products. We have our own brand which is into female beauty product. There are multiple products in our brand and there are chances that the same raw material are used for different product with different label. For example, We can have multiple product having the same jar with different raw material in it.

Now let me explain my problem, I have 3 products that are having the same jar but the material filled in these jars and label are different. My finished/sellable product will be a complete product with jar, material and label on it.

Next we are having Daily Run Rate (DRR) of product. It means how many quantity of product do we sell daily from our store. So as explained, we have 3 product and their DRR as below. (**DRR is calculated on last 30 days stock consumption**)

```
+-----------------+-------------+
|    Product      |     DRR     |
+-----------------+-------------+
| Product1        | 100 qty/day |
| Product2        | 50 qty/day  |
| Product3        | 20 qty/day  |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

Now we have available finished product stock with us for this 3 product

```
+-----------------+------------+
|    Product      | Stock(qty) |
+-----------------+------------+
| Product1        | 2000 qty   |
| Product2        | 1000 qty   |
| Product3        | 1000 qty   |
+-----------------+------------+
```

As shown in the table above, there are 4000 finished products which means that there are 4000 jars that are converted to finished product. Apart from finished product I have 5000 more jars available with me.

I want to convert this 5000 jars into finished product such that all the stock will get finished after some specific days.

For example, I am having 2000 Product1 finished product and its DRR is 100. So I am having the stock of Product1 for 20 days. Same for others as below.

```
+-----------------+-----+------------+-------------+
|    Product      | DRR | Stock(qty) | Stock(days) |
+-----------------+-----+------------+-------------+
| Product1        | 100 |       2000 | 20 Days     |
| Product2        |  50 |       1000 | 20 Days     |
| Product3        |  20 |       1000 | 50 Days     |
+-----------------+-----+------------+-------------+
```

Here I need to do stock planning and for that I want to convert 5000 available jars into finished product in such a way that at particular date my all stock will be completed. So that before 15 days of completion of my stock I can plan for other stock.

For example on today I am having stock of each product available for different days like Product1 for 20 days, Product2 for 20 days and Product3 for 50 days. So after converting my 5000 Jars into finished product. My Product1, Product2 and Product3 will be available for approximately some (x) days. **This is what I want to achieve. I want the formula to calculate (x) days so that I can code the same in my code to display the same.**

> **Below information will be displayed to user on screen.**
>
> 1. Available Finished product stock and stock in days.
> 2. Available raw stock. And a text box where the user will enter the stock he/she want to convert to finished product. For example 7000 jars are in stock and user choosed to convert only 5000 jars to finished product.
> 3. If user choose to convert 5000 jars to product. Then after converting jars to finished product. For how many days the stock will be available.
> 4. Every day the availability of stock will change as per DRR
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1. DRR is calculated on the basic of stock consumed in last 30 days. (DRR can change everyday).
> 2. Consider that apart from jar all other raw material are available in excess quantity.

Answer (score 1):

I depends on available stock product have maximum time for consumption. What should other product are made such that they consumption finish at same day so formula be something like this

products_need_to_make=(product_max_time - current_prod)×rate_of consumption_of_current_product

Total material =sum of all product produce

If raw material is less then total material require then choose second highest time needed material

If raw material is more then distribute them to make all product such that time is same

Comment: how can i calculate product_max_time. Can you show with some example

Comment: It's 50 in your example

Comment: can you please show me the formula to calculate this. How does it derived?

Comment: It's based on that number of product available in stock;one of product need maximum time for consumption respective to other as in your case 50day is maximum; so you want to finish all product same time;you can't reduce time(50 days). So you make rest of product such that it's finish at after (50days); t days product already have in stock; so make 50-t days product that is (50-t)*product_consuption_day

Comment: As per this calculation. My all product will become available for 50 days. But still there will be available stock with me. I want the stock to be 0

Comment: Yes after above procedure rest of material will distribute uniform in all product as total_raw_remain_after_first_procedure×(rate_of_consuption(50,20,20)/sum_of_rate_of_all_product(50+20+20)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99816/discussion-between-naresh-teli-and-mohinuddin-luhar).